# jQuery event listener doesn't work in IE 7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, event-listener

the problem is a bit tricky. My code to dynamically load table rows inside a table and then attach events to all the Table cells doesn't work in IE7/8. But sometimes it does work for no apparent reason.

Here is a little sample:
http://jsbin.com/ivarus/6/edit

This is a simplified version of what I'm doing in my app

Here are the exact steps to repro:
1) Open IE and set to IE7/8 from dev tools (not necessary if you're already running IE8)
2) Navigate to http://jsbin.com/ivarus/6/edit
Expected: clicks attached to TD work in the Output section
Actually: the event listeners start working only after pressing "Run script"

In all other browsers (IE9+,Chrome,FF) this works immediately. Why? Am I doing something wrong ?Should I look for an alternative approach ?

Comment: You're iterating the array to `9`, while it only has `0` and `1`. The problem is probably the autoupdating in JSbin not working in older IE versions.

Comment: Well, it works for me in IE7 and IE8 If I save your code from JSBIN to HTML page and run on my machine without any issue. No Delay.

Comment: that is no surprise that IE7/8 does not supporting something unlike other browsers. i believe that is security issue with running scripts on IE7/8 that might contain unsecure content perticularly from different domain to render(only IE7/8 knows), also they are really sensitive towards errors no matter if they are syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the document ready event before your script runs. Enclose your code like this.

```
<script>
$(function ()
    {
        //your code here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

-- problem in append() not work on older IE

```
  if (($.browser.msie) & 
      (($.browser.version == '6.0') || ($.browser.version == '7.0')))
     {
       var oldHtml = $('#select').html();
       $('#select').html(oldHtml + appendInput);
     }
```