# Unable to attach event listeners to dynamically created elements in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, internet-explorer-8

**OVERVIEW:**

When I click a button i want to

- insert a new row at the end of a table
- copy the cells and contents from the first row of the table
- give unique ids to the elements within the cells
- assign a focus event listener to all inputs in the page.

**PROBLEM:**

The event handlers are not firing on the correct elements in IE8. For example if I focus on the last input in the table, the first input gets highlighted.

**CLARIFICATION:**

- This works in IE10, Chrome.
- Does not work in IE8 which is my target    browser.
- I know of ways
  to get around this.My aim is NOT to find a    workaround but to
  understand what my mistake is, in the given code.
- The example code is just a quick simplified version of the problem. I am not asking for code optimization thats not relevant to the question.
- Change event does not work too.

**CODE:**

*HTML:*

```
<table width="200" border="1" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='row0col0' name='row0col0'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

*JS:*

```
function addFocusListener() {
     $("input").unbind();
     $("input").each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         $this.focus(function () {
             var newThis = $(this);
             newThis.css('background-color', 'red');
         });    
     });
 }

 function addRowWithIncrementedIDs() {
     var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
     var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
     var row = table.rows[0];
     var rowNum = newRow.rowIndex;
     for (var d = 0; d < row.cells.length; d++) {
         var oldCell = row.cells[d];
         newCell = oldCell.cloneNode(true);
         newRow.appendChild(newCell);

         for (var c = 0; c < newCell.childNodes.length; c++) {
             var currElement = newCell.childNodes[c];
             var id = "row" + rowNum + "col" + d;
             $(currElement).attr('name', id);
             $(currElement).attr('id', id);
         }
     }
 }    
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#addRow").click(function () {
         addRowWithIncrementedIDs();
         addFocusListener();
     });
 });
```

**OTHER APPROACHES THAT WORK:**

1. changing from jQuery binding to regular JS binding. I.e from

   ```
   $this.focus(function () {....});
   ```

   to
   `this.onfocus =function () {....};`
2. Attaching the event handler as they are rendered.

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/GJvvu/

**RELATED LINKS IN SO:**

[jQuery event listener doesn't work in IE 7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458925/jquery-event-listener-doesnt-work-in-ie-7-8)

Comment: if literally changing from `$this.focus(` to `$this.onfocus =` fixes the problem, the problem is right there, though i suspect that's just a typo in your question.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: @KevinB well, i'd like to know what is the problem? Why does it not work the first way?

Comment: If the second way works, then $this isn't a jQuery object and that would be why the first way doesn't work. But seeing your code, that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @SLaks tried on 1.7.1,1.9.1 and 1.10.2

Comment: @KevinB That's what's confusing , there's no way $this is not a jQuery object and logging the $this gives me the correct input element.

Comment: What does `$this.jquery` give you (in the affected browser)

Comment: @KevinB $this.jquery gives me :1.10.2

Comment: That confirms it's definitely a jQuery object. `$this.onfocus = somefunction` should not be binding a focus event.

Comment: @KevinB my bad when I tried the $this.onfocus I actually had it as this.onfocus, not $this. Typo while writing the question. Will update the question now.

Comment: Is there some reason that you're using the .each there rather than just using .focus directly?

Comment: The area where you start working with childnodes raises a flag as a point where an issue could be occuring, can you log some information about that to make sure it's the same in the affected browser vs others?

Comment: @KevinB .focus() directly does not work too. :(

Comment: @KevinB I logged the entire table after every row addition and it looked perfect with unique and incremented IDs for each input element. Also logging the element right before the focus handler was being attached also showed that the handler was being attached to the correct unique element. Putting a log inside the event handler and logging 'this' gave the random element IDs.

Comment: So, logging `this.id` isn't giving you what you expect, correct?

Comment: @KevinB correct,inside the focus handler when element A is focused, its logging element X's id

Comment: Just for the hell of it, try changing the name of the input to something that isn't equal to the id. Also, to set the id, use `currentElement.id = id` rather than using `.attr`

Comment: These small things are just to try to narrow down what could be causing IE8 to be giving your inputs incorrect id's. At this point i think the issue you are having has nothing to do with the focus event.

Comment: @KevinB lol, heck ill try anything. I changed the names to be different with "blah"+random number. No dice. And you're right, as i said replacing focus() with change() also doesnt work when I perform a change action.

Comment: @KevinB and I get a "Object doesn't support this property or method" when I try to say currElement.id=id; Moving it before and after setting the name doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Hmmmm.... what is `currElement`? `console.log(currEelment)`

Comment: [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: And, if you were to log the id and name of the input immediately after setting it (using currElement), it shows the correct id/name?

Comment: Also, when you say random id, are you sure it isn't the first or last id of each row consistently, or is it truly random.

Comment: @KevinB "And, if you were to log the id and name of the input immediately after setting it (using currElement), it shows the correct id/name? " - Yes

Comment: @KevinB There is some strange pattern. Clicking any of the top 3 rows works and it highlights the correct input field. But any other row always highlights the first input field.

Comment: the first in each row, or the first overall. Are the top three rows generated in any way differently than the rest?

Comment: @KevinB first overall and nope nothing different, as u can see in the code above

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Sorry, I just noticed your comment that you want to understand the error in your code.
I can quickly tell you one error, and that is mixing jQuery and native DOM methods. If you have dedicated yourself to using a very powerful library, then use all of it's features, not just the ones you understand.

The below code uses event delegation (to fix your focusing problem) and jQuery methods to more simply add a row to the table than with native methods.

If you're going to use jQuery, then you might as well use it all the way:

```
var t = $('#myTable');

$(document)
    .on('focus','#myTable input',function() { 
        $(this).css('background','red') 
    })
    .on('click','#addRow',function() {
        //create a new row
        var 
            newIndex,
            r = t.find('tr').eq(0).clone();

        //append it to the table
        r.appendTo(t);

        //update newIndex - use it for later
        newIndex = r.index();

        //update the name/id of each of the inputs in the new row
        r.find('input').each(function() {
            var 
                el = $(this),
                id = 'row'+newIndex+'col'+el.closest('td').index();

                el.attr('id',id).attr('name',name);
        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GJvvu/1/

Comment: that's a neat way of doing it. Thanks and +1 for the code. But as I mentioned this is more of a knowledge question for me to understand why my code is not working. Thanks again though :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through your inputs and bind a focus handler to each of them, jQuery automatically collects all DOM elements that match the selector and performs it's focus API function on each of them:

Change this:

```
function addFocusListener() {
     $("input").unbind();
     $("input").each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         $this.focus(function () {
             var newThis = $(this);
             newThis.css('background-color', 'red');
         });    
     });
 }
```

To this

```
function addFocusListener() {
 $('input')
   .unbind()
   .focus(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color','red');
   });
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$("#addRow").live("click", function(){
 addRowWithIncrementedIDs();
 addFocusListener();
 });
```

Try out above code... this should work..

Comment: And it doesn't answer the question.